# Symmetric Matrix Inversion in C using CBLAS/LAPACK

Tags: c, lapack, blas, accelerate-framework, matrix-inverse

I am writing an algorithm in C that requires Matrix and Vector multiplications. I have a matrix ***Q*** (W x W) which is created by multiplying the transpose of a vector ***J***(1 x W) with itself and adding Identity matrix ***I***, scaled using scalar ***a***.

Q = [(J^T) * J + aI].

I then have to multiply the **inverse of Q** with **vector G** to get vector **M**.

M = (Q^(-1)) * G.

I am using *cblas* and *clapack* to develop my algorithm. When matrix **Q** is populated using random numbers (type float) and inverted using the routines *sgetrf_* and *sgetri_* , the calculated inverse is **correct**.

**But when matrix Q is symmetrical**, which is the case when you multiply (J^T) x J, the calculated **inverse is wrong!!**.

I am aware of the row-major (in C) and column-major (in FORTRAN) format of arrays while calling *lapack* routines from C, but for a symmetrical matrix this should not be a problem as A^T = A.

I have attached my C function code for matrix inversion below.

I am sure there is a better way to solve this. Can anyone help me with this?

A solution using cblas would be great...

Thanks.

```
void InverseMatrix_R(float *Matrix, int W)
{   
    int     LDA = W;
    int     IPIV[W];
    int     ERR_INFO;
    int     LWORK = W * W;
    float   Workspace[LWORK];

    // - Compute the LU factorization of a M by N matrix A
    sgetrf_(&W, &W, Matrix, &LDA, IPIV, &ERR_INFO);

    // - Generate inverse of the matrix given its LU decompsotion
    sgetri_(&W, Matrix, &LDA, IPIV, Workspace, &LWORK, &ERR_INFO);

    // - Display the Inverted matrix
    PrintMatrix(Matrix, W, W);

}

void PrintMatrix(float* Matrix, int row, int colm)
{
    int i,k;

    for (i =0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for (k = 0; k < colm; k++) 
        {
            printf("%g, ",Matrix[i*colm + k]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know BLAS or LAPACK, so I have no idea what may cause this behaviour.

But, for matrices of the given form, calculating the inverse is quite easy. The important fact for this is

```
(J^T*J)^2 = (J^T*J)*(J^T*J) = J^T*(J*J^T)*J = <J|J> * (J^T*J)
```

where `<u|v>` denotes the inner product (if the components are real - the canonical *bilinear* form for complex components, but then you'd probably consider not the transpose but the conjugate transpose, and you'd be back at the inner product).

Generalising,

```
(J^T*J)^n = (<J|J>)^(n-1) * (J^T*J), for n >= 1.
```

Let us denote the symmetric square matrix `(J^T*J)` by `S` and the scalar `<J|J>` by `q`. Then, for general `a != 0` of sufficiently large absolute value (`|a| > q`):

```
(a*I + S)^(-1) = 1/a * (I + a^(-1)*S)^(-1)
               = 1/a * (I + ∑ (-1)^k * a^(-k) * S^k)
                           k>0
               = 1/a * (I + (∑ (-1)^k * a^(-k) * q^(k-1)) * S)
                            k>0
               = 1/a * (I - 1/(a+q)*S)
               = 1/a*I - 1/(a*(a+q))*S
```

That formula holds (by analyticity) for all `a` except `a = 0` and `a = -q`, as can be verified by calculating

```
(a*I + S) * (1/a*I - 1/(a*(a+q))*S) = I + 1/a*S - 1/(a+q)*S - 1/(a*(a+q))*S^2
                                    = I + 1/a*S - 1/(a+q)*S - q/(a*(a+q))*S
                                    = I + ((a+q) - a - q)/(a*(a+q))*S
                                    = I
```

using `S^2 = q*S`.

That calculation is also much simpler and more efficient than first finding the LU decomposition.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answers has been very helpful.You previous comments,kept me thinking. When i first posted this question,I was just testing my C functions. During the test phase, I created matrix **Q** using (J^T) * J. This value of **Q** was passed to my inverse function, and as mentioned by you in the earlier comments, it can't be inversed.I should calculate Q completely Q = (J^T) * J + aI and pass it to my function. I just tried this theory in matlab and the results are as you suggested!!! **I think this should solve the problem with my code**.Thanks again for your help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Example for 3x3 matrix inversion, visit [sgetri.f](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/single/sgetri.f) for more

```
//__CLPK_integer is typedef of int
//__CLPK_real is typedef of float


__CLPK_integer ipiv[3];
{
    //Compute LU lower upper factorization of matrix
    __CLPK_integer m=3;
    __CLPK_integer n=3;
    __CLPK_real *a=(float *)this->m1;
    __CLPK_integer lda=3;
    __CLPK_integer info;
    sgetrf_(&m, &n, a, &lda, ipiv, &info);
}

{
    //compute inverse of a matrix
    __CLPK_integer n=3;
    __CLPK_real *a=(float *)this->m1;
    __CLPK_integer lda=3;
    __CLPK_real work[3];
    __CLPK_integer lwork=3;
    __CLPK_integer info;
    sgetri_(&n, a, &lda, ipiv, work, &lwork, &info);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net), which is an easy to use C++ wrapper for LAPACK.  It provides several inverse related functions:

- [inv()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#inv), general inverse, with an optional speedup for symmetric positive definite matrices
- [pinv()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#pinv), pseudo-inverse
- [solve()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#solve), solve a system of linear equations (that can be over- or under-determined), without doing the actual inverse