# How can I invert a Matrix in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, matrix, linear-algebra, vdsp

I am trying to solve a system of equations Ax = b in Objective-C. My A matrix is rectangular by nature so I am trying to find x by doing x = inv(A'*A)*A'*b. I am using vDSP to multiply and transpose the matrices but I need something to invert A'*A and I can't find any function to do that. Also, how am I support to set up my matrix. The size is variable right now I am doing the following and it gives me parameter type warnings.

```
int numberOfPlays = (int)[playArray count];
int numberOfSignals = (int)[signalMappings count];

float playElements[numberOfPlays][numberOfSignals];
...//set the values of playElements with playElements[i][j] = 2.0 or whatever value
float aTick[numberOfSignals][numberOfPlays];
```

and then I am using

```
vDSP_mtrans(*aMatrix, 1 , *aTick, 1, numberOfSignals, numberOfPlays);
```

Comment: why are you using `int`s instead of `NSUInteger`? seems like useless casting in this case.

Comment: also `NSArray` can only hold objects. you seem to want to store floats in one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282746/how-to-perform-matrix-inverse-operation-using-the-accelerate-framework